How to replace a parameter's value in json file with a value taken from a different text file
I have a a large number of JSON files on a Linux machine, where I need to change the value of a parameter with value taken from a different text file.
E.g.: If the JSON file has values like:
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "param1": "123",
      "param2": "456",
      "param3": "678",
      "param4": "123"
    }
  ]
}

and a text file xyz.txt, which has value like:
abc
efg
ijk

Here I need to replace the value of param2 with abc for 1st file and so on for each of the file present in the directory with values from xyz.txt.
Can anyone please help me, how I can do this ?

Do you always want to replace the value of the top-level key param2, in each file?  That last bit of the question was a bit unclear to me. Maybe show an example of what you want to produce?

In which order should the json files be processed since that affects which value they will get?

Do you need the formatting (spacing, indentation, string escapes, number formatting) to be preserved in those JSON files?

@StéphaneChazelas Shouldn't matter to a JSON parser...

@StéphaneChazelas : file should be processed in ascending order. and yes. formatting should be preserved.

@Kusalananda, yes, I need to always replace the value of param2 in each json file with values taken from a text file. for example, 1st json file will have abc as value for param2, 2nd json file will have efg as value for param2 .

Ascending lexical order? Or are there numbers in those file names that should be sorted numerically rather than lexically (like 10.json to come after rather then before 2.json)?

@StéphaneChazelas It should be sorted in numerically ascending order. like you mentioned, 10.json should come after 2.json

Please also add all information as requested in comments to your question or answers here in the question. People shouldn't have to read all the comments to understand what the question is about.

Create a list of the relevant files, then read the xyz.txt file line by line and modify the next file in the list (using the JSON processor jq).  End the process when you have finished reading the xyz.txt file or when you run out of files (whichever happens first).
#!/bin/sh -

while IFS= read -r value; do
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        printf 'Skipping "%s"\n' "$1" >&2
        continue
    fi

    jq --arg v "$value" '.customers |= map(.param2 = $v)' "$1" | sponge "$1"

    shift || break
done

This script uses jq to set the value of the param2 key in each element of the customers array in each JSON file given on the script's command line.  The modification is made "in place" using sponge (from the moreutils package).  The other way to do "in place" editing would be to write to a temporary file and then replace the original with that once the modification has been done.
The values are read from standard input.
You would run this as
./myscript ./*.json <xyz.txt

or, if you want your files to be processed in numerical order, and they have names like fileN.json, where N is some decimal integer, then use the zsh shell and call the script like
./myscript file<->.json(.n) <xyz.txt

The file<->.json(.n) pattern would expand to the numerically ordered filenames of regular files that start with file, then a number, and end in .json.  Note that the script itself does not have to be executed by zsh for this to work, it can still be run by sh as specified in its #!-line.
Testing with the given xyz.txt file and five JSON files.  The file names are given to the script by letting the shell expand the ./*.json globbing pattern on the command line.
$ ls
file1.json  file2.json  file3.json  file4.json  file5.json  xyz.txt
$ ./myscript ./*.json <xyz.txt
$ cat file1.json 
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "param1": "123",
      "param2": "abc",
      "param3": "678",
      "param4": "123"
    }
  ]
}
$ cat file3.json 
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "param1": "123",
      "param2": "ijk",
      "param3": "678",
      "param4": "123"
    }
  ]
}
$ cat file5.json 
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "param1": "123",
      "param2": "456",
      "param3": "678",
      "param4": "123"
    }
  ]
}


A variation that also parametrises the key that you want to replace. The key name is given as the 1st argument to the script, and the rest of the arguments are the filenames that we'd like to process.  The list of values is read from standard input as before.
#!/bin/sh -

key=$1; shift

while IFS= read -r value; do
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        printf 'Skipping "%s"\n' "$1" >&2
        continue
    fi

    jq --arg "$key" "$value" '.customers |= map(. += $ARGS.named)' "$1" | sponge "$1"

    shift || break
done

You would run this as, e.g.,
./myscript param2 ./*.json <xyz.txt


thanks for the answers. I tried the script you provided, but instead of replacing the value of desired parameter, it is creating a new parameter with the same name & adding value from xyz.txt
this is my json file format:
{
"customers": [
{
"param1": "123",
"param2": "456",
"param3": "678",
"param4": "123",
}

]
}
after running the script the output json is
{
"customers": [
{
"param1": "123",
"param2": "456",
"param3": "678",
"param4": "123",
}

],
"param2": "abc"
}

@vishal That's definitely what I would expect it to do with that JSON. If you have a JSON file with a very different structure compared to what you show in the question, I'm not surprised that you don't get the result that you want.  If you update the example JSON in the question (and also clarify what should happen if that custormers array contains more than one entry), then I could update my answer to cope with that.

@vishal See updated answer for a suggestion of how to deal with your new format.

I have updated the question. also I tried with the solution you suggested . Now it replacing the value as expected but removing the customers object. Now, I am getting output like this: [
{
"param1": "123",
"param2": "abc",
"param3": "678",
"param4": "123",
}

]
expected output is :
{
"customers": [
{
"param1": "123",
"param2": "abc",
"param3": "678",
"param4": "123",
}

]
}

@vishal That's because I forgot a single | in my code. I have now updated the whole answer to be in line with your updated question.
